# Why isn't my nat-to not applied to the pass out rule?

Tags: openbsd, nat, pf

I've a strange problem concerning NAT on an OpenBSD-Box with pf. I've cut down my pf.conf to the following lines:

```
extif = "pcn0"
intif = "pcn1"

block drop all

#Allow all incoming traffic from intif
pass in on $intif inet from $intif:network to any

#NAT everything which comes from intif and goes out on extif
match out on $extif inet from $intif:network to any nat-to $extif

pass out quick on $extif inet from $intif:network to any
```

This is not working somehow, the nat-to is not applied to the pass out rule. But if I use a rule like this:

```
[...]
match out on $extif inet from $intif:network to any nat-to $extif
pass out quick all
```

It is indeed working. And additionally if I do not work with the match-statement it works as well:

```
[...]
pass out quick on $extif inet from $intif:network to any nat-to $extif
```

This is really strange and not a solution because I want to restrict my rules further and apply the nat-to via match. Does anyone know why this is not working with match or where my typo is? (And yes IP-forwarding is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but might as well answer...

The 'match' rule rewrites the address to $extif ....see the problem yet?

The following pass doesn't take this into account and ...packet on the floor ...well /dev/null or

I'd recommend adding a 'tag ALLOWED' onto the end of the 'match' rule and then change the pass rule:

```
pass out quick on $extif tagged ALLOWED
```